# Name of a specific room in radiology department in hospital where doctors write images' descriptions

Tags: nouns

What is the proper name (if there is any) of the room where doctors write descriptions of various radiology images. This room typically has a bit different light, some special grey-scale-only-monitors to evaluate MRI or X-REY images. It's not a typical "doctor's office"

I have this question because in my country we have a name for it, but I tried to google English equivalent with no luck.

Comment: I guess I would say something like "radiology evaluation room" or "radiology evaluation department".  But, then, although I probably glow in the dark, I've never been on that side of the X-ray machine.

Comment: (Google suggests "radiology reading room".)

Comment: http://redricktechnologies.com/Products/ReadingRoomDesign.aspx

Comment: http://www.itnonline.com/article/designing-perfect-reading-room

Comment: Just 'reading room'

Answer (score 1):

It's called the ***reading room***.

I couldn't find a formal definition to cite, but the following abstracts from radiology journal articles use the term in context, making the meaning clear:

> - One hundred patients ... were retrospectively read by two readers ... Reading was performed in a dedicated reading room with ambient light conditions.[¹](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26438423)
> - In this article, we describe the variety of disruptions that arise in the reading room environment ...[²](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26122926)
> - This article describes the creation of a virtual workstation for use by medical students and implementation of that workstation in the reading room.[³](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25714314)
> - Activity experienced during reading room-based work and interventional work was compared by studying 4 additional radiology residents ...[⁴](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26675263)